# What are some common tagging strategies for EC2 in multi-team environments?

Tags: amazon-ec2, configuration, amazon-web-services, cloud, cloud-computing

Given a company with multiple teams using EC2, what are some common or practical strategies for setting some TAG guidelines when instances or ami's are created so that resources can be more easily searched and filtered?

Comment: CloudFormation automatically tags all the resources created so it's a nice way to keep track of things.

Answer (score 0):

Initially we tried making tags mandatory for everyone creating the VM to use tags in the following format.

> ```
> name [name of the person creating the vm] 
> project [project for the vm created for] 
> team [team the VM belongs to]
> purpose [what is the VM used for] 
> application [what application will be served on the vm]
> ```

This worked quite well. We improvised by creating a simple PHP form what would call EC2 API. The PHP form was validated so that all entries are valid, consistent and mandatory. Team and projects had list boxes.

Using simple fog.io EC2 api's, we would generate reports based on tags